# Creating different beamer frames using list-like syntax

Tags: beamer, lists, exam

I am trying to get \LaTeX\ to use a list style syntax for beamer. I need it for some very specific circumstances that each `\item` will dump all it's contents into a new frame.

To achieve that, I was hoping I could simply do a similar trick to what you do when you want to enclose every item of a list on different minipages environments:

```
    \newenvironment{framelist}{%
        \let\closeframe\relax%
        \newcommand\localframe{%
            \closeframe%
            \let\closeframe\endframe%
            \frame%
        }
    }
```

However, with the `\begin{frame} \end{frame}` environment there is no commands `\frame`, `\endframe` that could be used to open and close frames. So that would obviously not work (since it stores the whole content inside it as a macro).

After trying a few things and failing miserably I saw in another post in stackexchange that they were using `\long\def\bframe#1\eframe{\begin{frame}#1\end{frame}}` to "rename" the commands. However, even though syntactically it is similar to what a \minipage\endminipage commands do, they are still nothing like it:

```
    \newenvironment{framelist}{%
        \let\closeframe\relax%
        \newcommand\localframe{%
            \closeframe%
            \let\closeframe\eframe%
            \bframe%
        }
    }
```

And this doesn't work either... although the "error" it gives is a lot nicer, so maybe I am getting closer to noticing what idea could work?
I have become extremely desperate, so I was hoping someone over here could help me work this problem out.

Thanks!

PS:

Here is a M(not)WE, it doesn't compile, but it shows the basic premise of what I am looking for

```
    \documentclass{beamer}

    \long\def\bframe#1\eframe{\begin{frame}#1\end{frame}}
    \newenvironment{framelist}{
    \let\closeframe\relax %
        \newcommand{\localframe}{%
        \closeframe%
        \let\closeframe\endframe%
        \bframe%
    }
    }{%
    \eframe
    }
    \begin{document}

    \begin{framelist}
         \localframe
             bla
             bla, all of this in the first frame
         \localframe
             this should be on another frame entirely
         \localframe
             this should be another extra frame
    \end{framelist}
    
    \end{document}
```

Is there any solution to this problem? I feel there might just not be a solution to this

---

**EDIT:**

Adding example of what my "expansion" is suppose to do after the commands are brought down into beamer "basics".

When I write

```
    \begin{framelist}
         \localframe
             bla
             bla, all of this in the first frame
         \localframe
             this should be on another frame entirely
         \localframe
             this should be another extra frame
    \end{framelist}
```

I want it to "expand" to something similar to

```
    \begin{frame}
   
             bla
             bla, all of this in the first frame

    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}

             this should be on another frame entirely

    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}

             this should be another extra frame

    \begin{frame}
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you are trying to do. Can you show a short example of what your code looks like in another document class and specify what the output in beamer should look like?

Comment: @samcarter, I added an example of what exactly i want the commands to expand to after the "dust settles". I know maybe the syntax should be kept the beamer way, rather than play with it like I am trying to do. But the use that I want to give this piece of code requires these finicky details

Comment: Please see the edit to my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\newcommand{\choice}{whatever this macro should do}

\newenvironment{testlist}
{\begin{frame}[environment=testlist]}
{\end{frame}}

\begin{document}

\begin{testlist}
   \choice
   bla
   bla
\end{testlist}

\end{document}
```

(use at your own risk, may cause trouble if you need fragile content in your slides ...)

---

**EDIT:**

Based on the new code example in the question:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\newcounter{mycounter}

\newcommand{\localframe}{%
\ifnum\themycounter>0
    \framebreak%
\fi%
\addtocounter{mycounter}{1}%
}

\newenvironment{framelist}
{\begin{frame}[environment=framelist, allowframebreaks]\setcounter{mycounter}{0}}
{\end{frame}}

\begin{document}

\begin{framelist}
     \localframe
         bla
         bla, all of this in the first frame

     \localframe
         this should be on another frame entirely

     \localframe
         this should be another extra frame
\end{framelist}


\end{document}
```

*(but now the hacks start to get dirty...)*

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I intended. I will get back here if I encounter errors while I try to fix them. Although your solution is perfect, I wanted to add that there is a way to create that without using an added counter and the if statement that you used.
Here:
`\makeatletter
\newenvironment{framelist}
{
\let\closeframe\relax
\newcommand{\localframe}{
\closeframe
\let\closeframe\framebreak}
\begin{frame}[environment=framelist, allowframebreaks]}
{\end{frame}}
\makeatother
`

Comment: Maybe that would be worth adding to your answer in case other people try similar things. Also, would you mind expanding on exactly what does `\framebreak` do? And why does that command require @ to be added when used? I have never used that command before. Thank you again!

Comment: @A.Recuenco Please feel free to add your solution as an answer of your own! The `\makeateletter ... \makeatother` is actually unnecessary, it was a leftover from trying to use internal beamer counters instead of a new counter. `\framebreak` is similar to `\pagebreak`, it just pays attention to the mode you are in and acts differently for handout etc.

Comment: Just did that. May I ask, what do you think is better? The counter method? Or the method I am using? I don't know if using the let command is in any way unadvised for this kind of thing or not

Comment: @A.Recuenco From my point of few, I don't see any advantage/disadvantage between the two answers. All the disadvantages I can image are the same for booth, so I suggest you just use the one you like best?

Answer (score 1):

Following samcarter's recommendation I will add my own answer, improving on samcarter's answer, to prevent the use of a counter and preventing the uses of conditionals:

The key is simply knowing that `\framebreak` exists... which acts similar to a `\pagebreak.` And knowing one (of many) tricks to enclose items on a list within an environment.

(The only difference between my answer and samcarter is how we tell the first item's "close environment" to be disabled.)

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\newenvironment{framelist}%
{%
    \let\closeframe\relax%
    \newcommand{\localframe}{%
        \closeframe%
        \let\closeframe\framebreak%
    }%
    \begin{frame}[environment=framelist, allowframebreaks]%
}%
{\end{frame}}

\begin{document}

\begin{framelist}
     \localframe
        bla
        bla, all of this in the first frame

     \localframe
        this should be on another frame entirely

     \localframe
        this should be another extra frame
\end{framelist}

\end{document}
```